# How to handle an effect in a time series that enters the series at a later time?

Tags: time-series

*Disclaimer: I am relatively new to time series analysis, so I am not sure if my way of thinking makes sense.*

I have a time series of a few years, that I can model relatively well (respectable R squared, and normally distributed errors). However, in the last year of the data set, a series of effects  happened that I am almost sure of had a large combined effect on the observed variable. Evidence of this is the fact that for this year, the residuals are no longer normally distributed and show a large upward bias.

I would like to capture this 'combined effect' in the model, by looking at the residuals. I am wondering whether it is possible to regard the residuals as a sum of a signal (of this combined effect) and noise, and to model it accordingly.

Is this a valid method?

Comment: This *thing* which happened, can you include some variables in your model to account for this?

Comment: Welcome to CV, eork. Just as a comment: Perhaps you might study up on 'error correction models' as explicitly modeling part of the data generating process.

Comment: @user2974951 I have thought about adding a dummy variable, but it's not a constant effect. After it has started at time, say, t, it changes over time. If you have a suggestion as to how to model that, I would love to hear it.